# ASP ModalPopupControl + Wizard : Missing Assembly or Reference?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've looked around the web to find the answer to do with Compilation error I'm getting with a ASP web Form I have which makes use of afew using AJAX Control ToolKit controls.

So I have

```
<form>
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

 <div id="mainContent">   

      <asp:Button ID="booking" runat="server" Text="Add New Booking" />

      <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="booking"                            PopupControlID="Panel1" Drag="true" >
         </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

      <div id="Panel1" style="display: none;" class="modalPopup">
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
             <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Wizard ID="wizard" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0"  BackColor="#E6E2D8" 
                </asp:Wizard>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>                               
</div>
</form>
```

I have in web.config put in the required lines for AjaxControlToolkit :

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp"
         namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
         assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>      
 </pages>
```

Problem is when I add an even to wizard for `wizard_finishButtonClicked` (CodeBehind for this event is  `ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();`) so that I can hide the popup when the finish button in wizard is clicked. But I get compilation error saying:

```
CS1061: 'ASP.test_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'wizard_FinishButtonClick'
and no extension method 'wizard_FinishButtonClick' accepting a first argument of 
type 'ASP.test_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
reference?)
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your CodeBehind even handler should look like (VB):

```
Protected Sub Wizard_FinishButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles Wizard.FinishButtonClick
```

And the Wizard control is not part to the AJAX Control ToolKit, you should be able to test it without it.

Comment: I'm getting the similar error for every event i try to add, for example i tried adding an even to ImageButton Control  OnClick="ImageButton1_Click /> but its telling me "does not contain a definition for 'ImageButton1_Click' and no extension method 'ImageButton1_Click' accepting a first argument of type"

Comment: or remove thing form the page one by one. exemple, if you remove the update panel, then the modalpopup, then the panel, at the end if you only have the button and cant bind it to a click event, you got a problem elsewhere.